# Why do we have so many posts in the chat room written for computer programmers?

Tags: discussion, chat

In the last five hours the Pod Bay has

- [Stack Overflow Podcast #126 – The Pros and Cons of Programming with ADHD](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/29/stack-overflow-podcast-126-pros-cons-programming-adhd/)
- [My Most Embarrassing Mistakes as a Programmer (so far)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/29/my-most-embarrassing-mistakes-as-a-programmer-so-far/)

and about 24 hours ago:

- [Research update: Coding on the Weekends](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/28/research-update-coding-on-the-weekends/)

**Questions:**

1. Are these being pushed by SO, or do we "subscribe" to them?
2. Are these essentially soft advertisements of some kind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We get those because Stack Overflow Blog is one of our feeds. Since that is the official Stack Exchange blog, we have it as a feed so that we can quickly see any SE updates. The blog also happens to have a lot of material geared toward Stack Overflow specifically, but we can't tailor which posts we get from the feed except by deleting them from the chat room after they post. We could remove the Stack Overflow Blog feed if there was sufficient interest.

Comment: What would be the down side to making a separate room for feeds; one room for humans to communicate with each other and to post interesting/notable questions, the other for automated bot dumps?

Comment: The feed room would probably never get checked and sometimes feed stuff spawns discussion