# Is GdD no longer a mod candidate?

Tags: discussion, election

Just making sure there isn't some glitch.  All the other ones I have been reading about seem to be on the voting page.

Comment: I thought the same thing. Quite surprising

Comment: Ah, I was spelling their name wrong. Good to see they are still a user.

Comment: It isn't a glitch, I found in a new work assignment I was going to have very limited access to the web during the day, so I wouldn't be able to do moderate while at work. It sucks, but that is life!

Comment: Best wishes on your new assignment!

Comment: @GdD I hadn't seen this before commenting [here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/questions-for-space-exploration-mod-nominees/1461?noredirect=1#comment5490_1461). I also find it frustrating when life interferes with Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GdD removed their nomination within 10 minutes of the nomination window closing.